# SSRS 2008 R2 DynamicHeight enormous whitespace

Tags: ssrs-2008

Trying to make a horizontal stacked bar chart in 2008 R2, the number of rows is unknown until runtime so I'm using the dynamicheight property of the chart to increase as necessary - the chart space increases, but the chartarea inside of the chart has a great deal of whitespace above and below...

[image: Selecting TOP(5) Rows]

[image: Selecting TOP(50) Rows]

If I select 5 rows, I get the first image
If I select 50 rows I get the second, note the increase space between the border and "Chart Title" and between "Chart Title" and the actual chartarea
My DynamicHeight property is set to =(1 + COUNTROWS("DataSet1")/2) & " in"

note that I checked out the other StackOverflow question regarding extra whitespace at the bottom when switching to print format, but it doesnt seem to apply to me.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Connect submission: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/769305/ssrs-chart-dynamicheight-dynamicwidth-and-whitespace-management

Comment: I think this should have been a comment

Comment: This either needs more information, or it should just be a comment on the question. A simple link isn't a proper answer.